# Как переконвертировать архив формата tar.gz в формат tar.bz2?

Tags: архивация, tar, gzip

Есть архив в виде tar.gz, и его нужно скормить программе, которая требует на входе формат tar.bz2. Как осуществить конвертацию в *nix-like среде?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В этой задаче нам поможет магия потоков (standard streams) - можно на лету распаковывать gzip-архив и перепаковывать его в bzip2-архив, не создавая на диске промежуточный файл. Выглядеть команда будет так:

```
gunzip < file.tar.gz | bzip2 > file.tar.bz2
```

Если `file.tar.gz` Вам после перепаковки больше не нужен, нужно явно удалить его отдельной командой.

Для максимального (но менее быстрого) сжатия можно вместо `bzip2` написать `bzip2 -9`.